# Convolution of 2 uniform random variables $U(0,a)$ and $U(0,b)$

Tags: probability, convolution, uniform-distribution

> Let $X$ have a uniform distribution on $(0, a)$ and let $Y$ be independent of $X$ with a uniform distribution $(0, b)$. Let's say that $b$ is greater than $a$.
>
> **Q.** How can I determined the distribution of $S=X+Y$?

I'm trying to solve this, but I'm having trouble on how to handle the integral limits. I'm not really understanding how to build this problem properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we know that the pdf of $X$ and $Y$ are respectively:
$$
f_x(x)=\frac{1}{a}I_{(0,a)}(x) \quad f_y(y)=\frac{1}{b}I_{(0,b)}(y)
$$
We want to know the pdf of $S = X + Y$. By using convolution, we get:
$$
f_s(s)=\int f_x(s-y)f_y(y)dy
$$

Now, we have 3 cases:

- If $0<s<a$ then:

$$
f_s(s)=\int_0^s \frac{1}{ab}dy = \frac{s}{ab}
$$

- If $a<s<b$ then:

$$
f_s(s)=\int_{s-a}^s \frac{1}{ab}dy = \frac{1}{b}
$$

- If $b<s<a+b$ then:

$$
f_s(s)=\int_{s-a}^b \frac{1}{ab}dy = \frac{1}{ab}(b+a-s)
$$

In order to help visualing these cases:

[image: Visualisation]

Therefore, the pdf is:
$$
f_s(s) = \frac{s}{ab} I_{(0,a)}(s) + \frac{1}{b} I_{(a,b)}(s) + \frac{1}{ab}(b+a-s) I_{(b,a+b)}(s)
$$

Comment: The middle one is $1/b$, not $1/a$. (A sanity check to help see that is that what you wrote is not continuous.)

Comment: There's another copy of the same minor error at the bottom of the answer.